# Why does not it work- inputProps:{{maxLength:12}} - Mui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
 <Controller
              name="inn"
              control={control}
              render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
                <TextField
                  value={value}
                  onChange={handleChange(onChange)}
                  type="number"
                  inputProps={{
                    maxLength: 12,
                  }}
                  fullWidth
                  size="small"
                  placeholder="Например, 6163152794"
                  error={!!errors?.inn}
                  helperText={errors?.inn && errors.inn?.message}
                />
              )}
            />
```

[image]

I want to add a limit to 12, but it doesn't work for me, I don't know why, can you tell me

Answer (score 0):

It will not work when you set type as number, but you can achieve it like this:

```
 <TextField
   value={value}
   onChange={(e) => {
     const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
     if (e.target.value === '' || re.test(e.target.value)) {
       setValue(e.target.value)
     }
   }}
   inputProps={{
     maxLength: 12,
   }}
   fullWidth
   size="small"
   placeholder="Например, 6163152794"
   error={!!errors?.inn}
   helperText={errors?.inn && errors.inn?.message}
 />
```

Comment: I also have onChange